# Effect size and power

Tags: r, linear-model, effect-size, precision

I am a bit overwhelmed by all the information about effect sizes and power calculation here and I am not able to understand this.

I have a protein from source A and B. They both highly correlate. When it comes to test their ability to predict a continuous and categorical dependant variable, only the protein from source B is significant and the protein from source A is not (not even trending towards significance). This is from a linear regression model including co-variates. And the protein measures (from both sources) are log transformed.

My question(s) is: 
1. how to calculate the effect size - will this tell me how much more protein from source A will I need to test to get a significant value as much as protein from source B. 
2. reading upon calculating effect sizes -there are t-tests, F test etc. Which one do I use?
3. Is it right that I cannot use log transformed values of the protein to calculate effect sizes?

Ideally we want to test if we can use protein from source A as a surrogate to source B.

Any advice will be much appreciated.. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistical power is a pre-experiment notion based on the effect that if present one would not want to miss.  Data are not used to determine the needed effect size, except for informing one about the variability of $Y$.  I.e., you can use the observed standard deviation of a continuous $Y$ or prevelance of a binary $Y$ to assist in computing power to detect a given effect size.

The notion of precision is often more helpful, and is related to confidence intervals, which would also help you.  If a confidence interval for source A protein's effect is narrow and includes zero, you an better make a conclusion of minimal effect and stop there.  Otherwise, use this universal statistical "fact": if you achieve a certain confidence interval width now and all other things remain equal, having $4 \times$ the sample size would cut the confidence interval width in half.

Comment: So do you suggest I use confidence intervals rather than effect size?

Comment: Yes.  Confidence intervals apply whether or not you reject $H_0$, and they provide a way to avoid the "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence" error.